# NotesDocument.GetMIMEEntity always returns Nothing

Tags: vba, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am trying to create an Excel VBA macro that accesses the email documents of a Lotus Notes mailbox.

The following code checks the type of the `"Body"` `NotesItem` and whether `NotesDocument.GetMIMEEntity()` works after getting the `NotesDocument` with `Session.ConvertMime` set to `True` and to `False`.

```vb
Sub Test()
  Dim Session As NotesSession, DB As NotesDatabase, Doc As NotesDocument
  Set Session = GetSession("xxx")
  Set DB = Session.GetDatabase("", "yyy")

  Session.ConvertMime = False
  Set Doc = DB.AllDocuments.GetFirstDocument
  Debug.Print TypeName(Doc.GetFirstItem("Body")), Doc.GetMIMEEntity Is Nothing

  Session.ConvertMime = True
  Set Doc = DB.AllDocuments.GetFirstDocument
  Debug.Print TypeName(Doc.GetFirstItem("Body")), Doc.GetMIMEEntity Is Nothing

  Debug.Print TypeName(Doc.CreateMIMEEntity("Body2"))
End Sub
```

I was expecting to get this result:

```
IMIMEEntity False
IRichTextItem True
IMIMEEntity
```

Instead I get this:

```
IRichTextItem True
IRichTextItem True
IMIMEEntity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you REALLY sure, that the very first document in your database "AllDocuments" collection is a MIME Mail?

The "ConvertMime"- parameter is only relevant if there is MIME to convert. But mails can be completely NRPC routed and never converted to MIME. With default settings EVERY mail coming from one native Notes user using the Notes client going to another Notes user will be NotesRichtext and NOT Mime...

So: Your expectations are wrong for a large bunch of mails in a "normal" Notes/Domino environment.

Comment: Thanks, I thought `ConvertMIME` would do the opposite, that is convert a richtext to mime, not a mime to richtext.